# PHP WordPress Plugin - Not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a WordPress plugin using PHP which will display random lyrics to the index of the front end of the website. However it is not displaying at all to the front page. Am I using the wrong hook?

Below is my current code:

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: Lyrics
* Plugin URL: http://www.example.com
* Description: This plugin
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author: Joe Bloggs
* Author URL: http://www.example.com
* License: GPL2
*/

$lyrics = array (

    "I'm hurting, baby, I'm broken down" => "Marroon 5 - Sugar",
    "Lose yourself in the music" => "Eminem - Lose Yourself",
    "Love me like you do" => "Ellie Goulding - Love me like you do",
    "Armeno" => "Armeno - Youtube",

);


$display = array_rand($lyrics, 1);


function displaylyric() {
    echo "<p id='lryic'>$display</p>";
}

add_filter('the_content','displaylyric');

?>

?>
```

Also, if I wanted to attach this to a button prompt, how would I go about implementing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using global variables, but you are not accessing them correctly in your function. Try something like this:

```
function displaylyric() {
    global $display;
    echo "<p id='lryic'>$display</p>";
}
```

Maybe even better would be move the complete code inside `displayLyrics()` so as to avoid global variables.

Edit: also remove the two `?>` at the end of your file, they are probably causing an error.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot!

Any idea on how I could create a button within the_content which displays the artist of the lyric above when pressed?

Comment: @Kaoswarr, you could hide the lyrics with CSS, and create a button that shows it via JavaScript when clicked.